# What is varchar max size in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know in MySQL what is the maximum size is for a MySQL VARCHAR type.

I set `varchar(2500)`, but it's not taking data more that this limit I think. I increased size to `varchar(5000)` but it's not taking. Which datatype should I use for larger text?

I got warning message:

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'custom field value' at row 1

Comment: DId you try and google? This is a fairly simple question and the mysql docs should answer this.

Comment: Use text type which have unlimited size

Comment: VARCHAR can go to 65k, so your problem is somewhere else. Show us your code.

Comment: A good approach is [to search for your error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+Data+truncated+for+column).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **not** VARCHAR, which goes to 65k. Show us your code and we can help you figure out where the truncation is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

`Values` in `VARCHAR` columns are strings length. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used`.

for more string length you can use `Text`

Answer (score 0):

Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

For long texts you maybe should use blob: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

and for better practice you need to use TEXT instead for bigger text

Answer (score 0):

take the data type "TEXT" for large data, try this once